# Examples of music using II-V-III-IV major chord progression

Tags: chord-progressions

I happened to play a major chord progression of the type IIm-V-IIIm-IV (for example in C major: Dm-G-Em-F) and it sounds really good, I was interested in one thing in particular: a list of songs that use this progression to hear how it sounds or how it is arranged.

Comment: Sorry, but this site doesn't cater for such questions, as you'll see when you read the Help Centre.